# Laravel blade Variable issues -> undefined index

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am facing some issues when passing a variable to my view with an image path.

When I trying to use this to get the image path

```
@foreach ($data as $dat)
<img class="img-responsive" src="{{ $dat['_embedded']['wp:featuredmedia']['0']['source_url'] }}" alt="">
@endforeach
```

I get this error

```
Undefined index: wp:featuredmedia (View: /Users/sam/Documents/development/shop/resources/views/landing-page.blade.php)
```

When I use only `{{ $dat['_embedded']['wp:featuredmedia']['0']['source_url'] }}`
I get the correct path to the image without an error.

How can I fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: what contains the `$data` ? output of `dd($data);`

Answer (score -1):

Using this `{{ $dat['_embedded']['wp:featuredmedia']['0']['source_url'] }}` without quotes is perfectly fine.